# add nodes to Foreman

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, foreman

I'm completely confused how I can add my servers to Foreman. I've setup a Foreman server, I pointed the /etc/puppet/puppet.conf "server" directive to my Foreman server, and I under "Provisioning=>Smart Proxy" I see the signature requests. I've signed them via the web-interface, but when I go to "Hosts=>All hosts", only the Foreman server is listed there.

What do I need to get my servers added to this list, so I can manage the servers via Puppet?

this is the puppet.conf file I use on my servers:

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post

[agent]
server = foreman.srv.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client needs to do a puppet run. After that it will appear in foreman

Comment: There is no critique. He just needs to do a puppet run on the clients. That's all. Foreman will show hosts that where created through the interface, or have facts loaded in his database or puppetdb

Comment: Hi, it seemed that the Puppet agent was disabled by default on Ubuntu. After I run "puppet agent --enable" and "puppet agent --test", the hosts were added.